# Is it possible to cause a deadlock when using thread-safe .NET 4+ collections?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

Are the collections in System.Collections.Concurrent fully thread-safe in all cases? Or is it theoretically possible to cause a deadlock when using multiple concurrent collections from multiple threads?

Thanks.

Comment: Thread safety is the whole point of this namespace...

Comment: @ken2k Yes, but just being in that namespace doesn't make *everything* thread safe...

Comment: You need to define what you mean by thread safety.  [It doesn't really have a formal definition](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/10/19/what-is-this-thing-you-call-thread-safe.aspx).

Comment: Servy, that was a good read. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The classes are (for the most part) thread safe, as documented on MSDN.  For example, the [documentation for `ConcurrentQueue<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265.aspx) explicitly states:

> All public and protected members of ConcurrentQueue are thread-safe and may be used concurrently from multiple threads.

All required synchronization is handled internally.

Also note that some types have some minor thread safety issues, such as `BlockingCollection<T>.Dispose()`, which is not thread safe, but [again documented on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312.aspx):

> The Dispose method is not thread-safe. All other public and protected members of BlockingCollection are thread-safe and may be used concurrently from multiple threads.

That being said, if you're doing your own synchronization, you may be causing dead locks unrelated to the usage of these types.  If you're experiencing dead locks, it's most likely due to some other synchronization in your code or a library you're using.

Answer (score 6):

Well, some of the types can certainly be used in ways that cause deadlocks.  For example, [BlockingCollection.Take](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287085.aspx) blocks until an element is available, so if you call this on the UI thread and some background thread that the produces items for the Take winds up having to synchronize something through the UI thread (say there's a COM dependency that marshals silently in the background), you can deadlock.  As always when dealing with threading, a reasonable level of paranoia is recommended, even when using 'thread safe' classes.